Why does mypy give an error: Generator has incompatible item type "Sequence[str]"?
I've used mypy to type-check rbast.py from this post:
https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=19931c644949c29b715b797a90b59a01
It gives three errors. The first two are obvious, but the third is:
main.py:38: error: Generator has incompatible item type "Sequence[str]"; expected "str"  [misc]
How do I need to change the code to fix this error?

Please include [mre] code here.

Here's the problematic code:
        for arg_repr in product(*arg_reprs, *kw_reprs):
            arg_list = ", ".join(
                f"{arg[0]}: {arg[1]}" if isinstance(arg, tuple) else arg
                for arg in arg_repr
            )

product yields tuples, so arg is a tuple. It's not clear what if isinstance(arg, tuple) else arg is for, you should be able to remove that whole snippet entirely. mypy's problem seems to be that the else arg might happen in which case your generator contains some tuples, not just strings.

Thanks for your help!
I think, product yields tuples, so arg_repr is a tuple. It looks like arg can either be a string (if it comes from arg_reprs) or a tuple itself (from kw_reprs).
The isinstance check should convert the latter to a string also, so only strings are passed to join. Is there a particular reason that mypy is unable to deduce that?

Oh right, sorry. You could try using reveal_type on various things to see what it thinks the types of those things are. There's lots of things mypy and type checkers in general are not good at deducing.
